# When generating a rigify rig, no controls for my dragon's jaw are created

Tags: armature, rigify

The head is composed of a head sample, first head bone at the end of the neck and two duplicates of that bone in the head and jaw themselves. It never generates anything past the neck and pieces cannot be individually controlled.

I would very much appreciate any help, and sadly cannot attach any images as imgur isn't cooperating. I will try to update this post from home as soon as I can.

Edit: I have managed to extend it to control the head, but the jaw is still uncontrollable

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you assigned a *Rig Type* to the jawbone in *Pose* mode in the *Bone Properties* tab? It looks like that you want a simple jaw without deformation for the mouth, so maybe the *Rig Type* "[basic.super_copy](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/basic.html#basic-super-copy)" might be what you are looking for. In its options, you can choose if a control bone should be created (checkbox) and what it should look like (Widget).

Comment: I have been messing with them, but haven't tried this which solved my problem. After posting on 3 communities and 2 subreddits, I finally have a solution. Thank you